# kube-ui service with load balancer support

Tags: kubernetes

I have just deployed a (perfectly working) kubernetes cluster (on AWS) using the standard `kube-up` script.

I have noticed that the script starts automatically the `kube-ui` pod on the cluster. It also starts the associated service (located at `./cluster/addons/kube-ui/kube-ui-svc.yaml`).

I can curl the kube-ui service just fine from one of the minions.

However, the service yaml doesn't contain the `type = LoadBalancer` parameter and so the kube-ui doesn't get associated to an external AWS load balancer.

I was wondering what the right / recommended procedure to generate load balancer  would be. I am thinking of:

- deleting the kube-ui service.
- editing the yaml to include the `type = LoadBalancer` parameter
- re-launching the kube-ui service.

Or is there another "best practice"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `kubectl edit svc kube-ui --namespace=kube-system`?

Comment: Hi @vishnu I tried that but that only opens an editor that allows me to modify the service. Sounds like a shortcut to the stop service, edit, restart service? But doesn't answer the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I missed something (an output) during the initial setup. For other reasons I had to redeploy the k8s cluster and I have noticed that, at the very end, the kube-up script outputs a number of information including how to externally access these services the master public IP address.

E.g:

Cluster validation succeeded
Done, listing cluster services:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://<redacted>
Elasticsearch is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/elasticsearch-logging
Heapster is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
Kibana is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kibana-logging
KubeDNS is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
KubeUI is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-ui
Grafana is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana
InfluxDB is running at https://<redacted>/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb
```

As you can see the kube-ui service can be reached from the outside via this proxy mechanism (which seems to be working fairly well) that has been configured as part of the setup on AWS.

Now onto understanding more about this proxy service.